# Netlify CMS Images are uploaded into wrong Media folder

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms

This is my config.yml for Netlify CMS

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master
  repo: franva/askwinston

  commit_messages:
    create: 'Create {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    update: 'Update {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    delete: 'Delete {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    uploadMedia: '[skip ci] Upload “{{path}}”'
    deleteMedia: '[skip ci] Delete “{{path}}”'

media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img
publish_mode: editorial_workflow
local_backend: true

collections:
  - name: "blog"
    label: "Blog"
    folder: "src/pages/blog"
    create: true
    media_folder: static/img
    public_folder: /img
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Template Key", name: "templateKey", widget: "hidden", default: "blog-post"}
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime"}
      - {label: "Description", name: "description", widget: "text", required: false}
      - {label: "Featured Post", name: "featuredpost", widget: "boolean", required: false}
      - {label: "Featured Image", name: "featuredimage", widget: image, required: false}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
      - {label: "Tags", name: "tags", widget: "list"}

  - name: "pages"
    label: "Pages"
    create: true
    files:
      - file: "src/pages/index.md"
        label: "Landing Page"
        name: "index"
        fields:
          - {label: "Template Key", name: "templateKey", widget: "hidden", default: "index-page"}
          - {label: Title, name: title, widget: string}
          - {label: Image, name: image, widget: image}
          - {label: Subheading, name: subheading, widget: string}
          - {label: Mainpitch, name: mainpitch, widget: object, fields: [{label: Description, name: description, widget: text}]}
          - {label: Intro, name: intro, widget: object, fields: [{label: Heading, name: heading, widget: string}, {label: Description, name: description, widget: text}, {label: Blurbs, name: blurbs, widget: list, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Text, name: text, widget: text}]}]}
          - {label: Main, name: main, widget: object, fields: [{label: Heading, name: heading, widget: string}, {label: Description, name: description, widget: text}, {label: Image1, name: image1, widget: object, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Alt, name: alt, widget: string}]}, {label: Image2, name: image2, widget: object, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Alt, name: alt, widget: string}]}, {label: Image3, name: image3, widget: object, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Alt, name: alt, widget: string}]}]}
      - file: "src/pages/about/index.md"
        label: "About"
        name: "about"
        fields:
          - {label: "Template Key", name: "templateKey", widget: "hidden", default: "about-page"}
          - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
          - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
```

As you can see that I have set the Media and Public folders to `static/img` and `/img` respectively for both root and collections level.

But when I upload a file from the admin blog editor, it still updates images to
`/root/src/pages/blog/static/img` rather than the `/root/static/img` folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should remove those lines under the Blog collection :

```
    media_folder: static/img
    public_folder: /img
```